# specified method is not supported

Tags: c#, oracle

Trying to retrieve a single value from an oracle database table, with the code below

```
public int _getProductPrice(string product_id)
    {
    Int16 price = 0;
       string query = string.Format(@"select sum(price) price from sales where product_id = '{0}'", product_id);
       string connectionString = String.Format("SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST={0})(PORT={1}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME={2})));uid={3};pwd={4};", AppConfig.OraDBHOST, AppConfig.OraDBPORT, AppConfig.OraDBNAME, AppConfig.OraDBUSER, AppConfig.OraDBPWD);
       using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
       {
           OracleCommand cm = new OracleCommand(query);
           try
           {
              cm.Connection = connection;
              connection.Open();
              OracleDataReader reader = cm.ExecuteReader();
              reader.Read();
              price = reader.GetInt16(0);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                throw new Exception(e.Message);
            }
        }
       return price;
       }
```

However the exception returns the "specified method is not supported", not sure which method.
What am i getting wrong?

Comment: pls. provide some more details like the stacktrace. Maybe there is even an inner exception? What type of exception was thrown?

Comment: Remove the `catch`. All you're doing by throwing a new exception is destroying the stack trace with the actual place where the error happened.

Comment: The `.GetInt16` looks fishy. What's the actual type of the `price` column? I doubt it's a 16-bit integer.

Comment: If all you want is one value, `.ExecuteScalar` is faster than `.ExecuteReader`. This will also give you a chance to inspect the actual type.